# Apply filtering on ModelChoiceField in Django-admin inline section

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm stuck in filtering a `ModelChoiceField` in Django-admin section using `NestedTabularInline`. Trying to get it right using a custom `ModelForm` to provide a `queryset` for the `ModelChoiceField`.
I want to filter the **plan method** on the selected **plan activity** (which is parent). See picture below:

[image: Admin site with nested inlines]

2 problems trying to fix this:

1. The `print(filter_id)` generates only output when the first relation is stored in the database, which makes sense. But of course you want to filter your first `PlanMethod` as well.
2. I can't figure out how to create the queryset correctly. `get(id=11)` works but I need to plug in the `self.instance` in some way. The output from `filter_id` looks like this:

[image: Output from print(filter_id)]

Some suggestions needed here.

model.py:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    activity = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.activity

class Method(models.Model):
    method = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.method

class PlanActivity(models.Model):
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    position  = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('position', )

class PlanMethod(models.Model):
    planactivity = models.ForeignKey(PlanActivity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    method = models.ForeignKey(Method, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    position  = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('position', )
```

admin.py:

```
class PlanMethodAdminForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PlanMethodAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        filter_id = self.instance.planactivity_id
        print(filter_id)
        self.fields['method'].queryset = Method.objects.filter(
            activity_id=PlanActivity.objects.get(id=11).activity_id
            )

class PlanMethodAdminInline(SortableHiddenMixin, NestedTabularInline):
    model = PlanMethod
    sortable_field_name = "position"
    extra = 0
    form = PlanMethodAdminForm
        
class PlanActivityAdminInline(SortableHiddenMixin, NestedTabularInline):
    model = PlanActivity
    sortable_field_name = "position"
    extra = 0
    inlines = [PlanMethodAdminInline]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:: [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from app.models import Method
from django import forms

class PlanMethodAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PlanMethodAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    
   class Meta:
    model = Method
    fields = '__all__'

class PlanMethodAdminInline(admin.ModelAdmin):
sortable_field_name = "position"
extra = 0
form = PlanMethodAdminForm
list_filter = ['method']
search_fields = ['method']
admin.site.register(Method, PlanMethodAdminInline)
```

i hope this help it, grettings

Comment: Hi John, many thanks for your response. This is not the right answer although. The list_filter and search_field methods are living in the admin list views page (you are right if I changed the NestedTabularInline to ModelAdmin). But because I'm using NestedTabularInline you will actually never come across this list view. I want the filtering to be done specifically in the ModelChoiceField.